# Unable to Close Window using remote in Electron JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, electron

I have tried the following code to close a frameless window in Electron JS. But the window does not close when button is clicked. I am new for Electron, I am stuck here now.

```
const electron = require('electron');
const path = require('path');
const remote = electron.remote;

const closeBtn = document.getElementById('closeBtn');

closeBtn.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    var window = remote.getCurrentWindow();
    window.close();
});
```

Please tell me what I am supposed to do now.
Thanks in advance...

Comment: Run `console.log(window)` before `window.close()` - what do you see?

Comment: Actually I did try that, it did not log anything. However I got the problem solved, where node is not integrated and it should be integrated by adding `webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: true
 }` to the new BrowserWindow Declaration. Which I did not do earlier. Anyways thanks for your effort. Really appreciate that...

Answer (score 1):

I got the problem solved. I had to add the following property to the new BrowserWindow Declaration.

```
webPreferences: {
        nodeIntegration: true
}
```

Although it is has not been necessary for older versions, for newer versions it is.